# Docker - Build Arg in Source File

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to build a Docker container whose source tag I want to pass as a parameter.

Build script:

```
docker build \
    --pull=true \
    ...
    --build-arg version=${version}
```

The Dockerfile:

```
ARG version

FROM registry/repo:${version}
```

Running this gives me the error `Please provide a source image with`from`prior to commit`.

Is there any way I can pass the version to pull as a build argument and use it? I'm on docker version `1.12`

Comment: _"Please provide a source image with from prior to commit"_ means that you have to use `FORM` before being able to use `ARG` in your Dockerfile.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[According to the docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/format), the first instruction needs to be `FROM` (or technically a parser directive, but not relevant here) so this approach likely isn't going to work. Probably some shell wrapper around `docker build...` with some `sed` command or something to insert the correct version, or a template of some kind.

[Gareth Rushgrove had a nice talk at DockerCon16](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IyuyA8rSBAo) on image build tooling that might be interesting.

Update (7/2/17): This is [now possible to achieve since v17.06](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-arg-and-from-interact).

Comment: This has since been changed, see https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/31352

Comment: looks like ARG can come before FROM

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-arg-and-from-interact