# GitLab building in DinD fails with 'Please provide a source image with `from` prior to commit'

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, docker-in-docker

I have a Dockerfile with ARG before first FROM.
It builds correctly on my server (Docker version 20.10.7) however when I try to build it as part of GitLab CICD (GitLab version 13.7.4) within a DinD container (image docker:20.10.7) the build fails with the following message:

```
Please provide a source image with `from` prior to commit
```

I'll appreciate help with resolving this issue.

Thanks,
Barak

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker - Build Arg in Source File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40273070/docker-build-arg-in-source-file)

Comment: Thanks Nicolas, unfortunately the question refers to an older version of Docker, in which ARG couldn't come before FROM. The Docker version I'm using (20.10.7) should allow it.